# wxPython - modify a frame

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a simply code:

```
import wx

class Glowne(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        pos = 55
        tekst = 'HELLO - position'
        font = wx.Font(18, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        wx.StaticText(self, -1, tekst, (300, pos)).SetFont(font)

        btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Change pos", (345, 100))
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, Program.zmiana, btn)

class Program(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY,'Program')
        panel_one = Glowne(self)
        self.SetSize((800,600))
        self.Centre()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = Program()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

How can I modyfy pos variable after hitting "Change pos" button?
In my real program I have something like:
    name
    name1
    name2

```
"BUTTTON"
```

I would like to add wx.TextCtrl method between name2 and button after hitting "BUTTON". I need to modyfy a frame (add place beetwen name2 and button). I do not know how can I achieve that.

EDIT. There is a code I need to modify:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    global odstep
    self.panel = wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
    odstep = 0
    odstep1 = 0
    font = wx.Font(13, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
    for name in config['rewir1']:
        nazwa_zliczana = config['rewir1'][name]
        odstep += 22
        self.name1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, name, (300, 10 + odstep))
        self.name1.SetFont(font)
        btn_usuwanie = wx.Button(self, -1, u"Usuń", (475, 10 + odstep))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt, i: Program.Usuwanie(evt, i), btn_usuwanie)
    wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'PART I', (365, 0), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER).SetFont(font)
    odstep1 = odstep + 50
    print odstep
    for name in config['rewir2']:
        nazwa_zliczana = config['rewir2'][name]
        odstep1 += 22
        self.name2 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, name, (300, 50 + odstep1))
        self.name2.SetFont(font)
        btn_usuwanie_2 = wx.Button(self, -1, u"Usuń", (475, 50 + odstep1))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt, i: Program.Usuwanie(evt, i), btn_usuwanie_2)
    print odstep1
    wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'PART II', (365, 80 + odstep), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER).SetFont(font)
    self.btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Change panel", (345, 500))
    self.btn_dodaj_rewir1 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Add name", (345, 42 + odstep))
    self.btn_dodaj_rewir2 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Add name", (345, 84 + odstep1))
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.new_name, self.btn_dodaj_rewir1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to save `wx.StaticText` instanced. To change property of it later.

  - Use `SetPosition` method to change position.
- Bind `EVT_BUTTON` event to event handler (`change_pos` in the following code).

---

```
class Glowne(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        tekst = 'HELLO - position'
        font = wx.Font(18, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        self.text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, tekst, (300, 55))  # Save for later use
        self.text.SetFont(font)

        btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Change pos", (345, 100))
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.change_pos)

    def change_pos(self, event):
        x, y = self.text.Position
        self.text.SetPosition((x, y + 10))
```

Comment: I have another problem. In my program there is a for loop. I need to modify positions of all items. When I use SetPosition it takes only last item from loop. Any ideas?

Comment: @Luk, Could you post another new question with code that demonstrate your issue?

Comment: I modified my question and added some code. Should I start new topic?

Comment: @Luk, "new" question please.